# Call MS Access Module via VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2010

Is it possible to call a function in a module in MS Access with VB.net?

I have codes in my laptop using *Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access* but all objects I declare under .Access is ambiguous, so I want to try other options.

This is for educational and experimental use only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by using automation: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;306682

```
Case "Access"

    Dim oAccess As Access.ApplicationClass

    'Start Access and open the database.
    oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    oAccess.Visible = True
    oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("c:\db1.mdb", False)

    'Run the macros.
    oAccess.Run ("DoKbTest")
    oAccess.Run("DoKbTestWithParameter", "Hello from VB .NET Client")

    'Clean-up: Quit Access without saving changes to the database.
    oAccess.DoCmd().Quit (Access.AcQuitOption.acQuitSaveNone)
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject (oAccess)
    oAccess = Nothing
```

Comment: I should use "Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access" right? Because I'm having a hard time troubleshooting the ambiguity. It must be framework incompatibility or something. Thanks!